# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not changing the property I am passing to a previous View

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to pass data from a `tableview` to a previous screen, which is my *Sign Up* screen. Specifically what I am sending is the name of a school.

What is happening is that when I return to the previous screen through the segue, the label I am changing (`schoolTextLabel`) is showing "None Selected", when I want it to display the school name. Through some error checking, I have found that when I have it `println(theSchoolName)`, it is correctly choosing the name I want displayed, It is just not passing the value to the other screen.

Please help!
I have searched endlessly on the internet for the answer and cannot for the life of me find the answer.
Thank you!

**TableViewController**

```
var namesArray = [String]()
var locationsArray = [String]()

var theSchoolName = "None Selected"


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "selectedSchool" {
        var completeSignUpVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SignUpViewController
        completeSignUpVC.school = self.theSchoolName
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.theSchoolName = self.namesArray[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedSchool", sender: self.namesArray[indexPath.row])

    println(theSchoolName)
}
```

**SignUpViewController**

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var schoolTextLabel: UILabel!
var school = "No School Selected"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
    self.schoolTextLabel.text = self.school        
    usernameSignupText.delegate = self
    passwordSignupText.delegate = self   
}
}
```

Comment: Just because you've assigned a string to a label doesn't mean that any time you update the string, the label is updated. You need to update the label by setting it's text property, most likely in ViewWillAppear. Also, `prepareForSegue` is not called when navigating backwards in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I did not use a UINavigationController, it is just a View Controller with the table and a cancel button at the top. It is getting called, and I know this because "None Selected" is appearing instead of "No School Selected", so the label IS getting updated, however it is supposed to be sending whatever I select in the table. Do you know a fix for this or need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to find the selected row index, and then call that number in the namesArray. I'm not exactly sure why my previous code didn't work, but this now works.

```
var selectedRowIndex = self.schoolTable.indexPathForSelectedRow()
var completeSignUpVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SignUpViewController
completeSignUpVC.school = namesArray[selectedRowIndex!.row]
```